# A random variable X has an absolutely continuous distribution whose density f(x) is proportional to

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$f(x)$ is proportional to x on $0 \leq x \leq 1$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. What is $P\{X \in  (\frac{1}{3},\frac{7}{9})\}$

Now I know that the density function is $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\;\mathrm dx$$
and $f(x) =0$ otherwise. Where I'm stuck is what should $f(x)$ be.

If someone could help finding $f(x)$, so I can continue.

---

$$\int_{0}^{1} c\,x \;\mathrm dx= c\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]^1_0 \\~\\\therefore\; c=2$$

Then $$\int_{{1}/{3}}^{{7}/{9}}2\,x \;\mathrm dx= \frac{40}{81}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Proportional to $x$ means $f(x) = cx$ for some $c$. Now use the fact that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx= 1$ to find $c$. Then integrate $f$ over $(\frac 13,\frac 79)$.

Comment: Oh okay, that was the point I needed that $f(x) =cx$, I will work on the problem and update it. Thank you

Comment: The update was correct  (formatting a *bit* unclear but identifiable; fixed)

Comment: Thanks, so everything is good right?